# How to resolve error message in aggregate SD function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run an aggregate SD function, but I'm getting an error message I can't resolve, or else I'm getting output that doesn't work. I'm including sample data- the goal is to run on a larger data set, but I can't even get the aggregate function to work on these three columns.

```
dput(droplevels(controls2[1:20, 1:3]))
structure(list(Experiment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ceres- Clipping", 
"FGI- Defoliation"), class = "factor"), Grain = c(489.9, 698.5, 
430.6, 244.9, 476.5, 545.4, 570.2, 463.1, 285.1, 407.6, 244.9, 
401.9, 126.3, 179.9, 382.7, 266, 653, 653, 606.6, 606.6), Environment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Morris.1", "St. Paul.1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(3565L, 
3566L, 3567L, 3568L, 3569L, 3570L, 3571L, 3572L, 3573L, 3574L, 
3575L, 3576L, 3577L, 3578L, 3579L, 3580L, 2379L, 2380L, 2381L, 
2382L), class = "data.frame")

controlSDs <- aggregate(x = controls2, by = list(controls2$Experiment, controls2$Environment), FUN = "sd")
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

However, the only column that I'm trying to perform `sd()` on, `controls2$Grain`, is numeric:

```
names(controls2)
[1] "Experiment"  "Grain"       "Environment"

class(controls2$Grain)
[1] "numeric"
```

I understand `controls2$Environment` and `controls2$Experiment` are factors, but I have run this command before with factors in the `by = list()` command and it has worked. I've also tried the following:

```
controlSDs <- aggregate(cbind(Experiment, Environment) ~ Grain, data = controls2, sd)
```

Which does not return an error message, however, the values for `controlSDs$Experiment` and `controlSDs$Environment` have been replaced with 0s and NAs such that I cannot use them to combine the data set with a data frame of means calculated using a similar aggregate function.

```
head(controlSDs)
Grain Experiment Environment
1   0.0          0           0
2  30.0         NA          NA
3  44.0         NA          NA
4  44.3         NA          NA
5  46.0         NA          NA
6  48.0         NA          NA
```

Any advice on how to get this aggregate SD function to work correctly would be much appreciated. I would be happy with a solution that simply allows me to calculate the SD of the Grain column, but ideally I could scale this up to a 100+ column of a data set that is entirely numeric aside from the Environment and Experiment columns. I've updated R and R Studio within the last two weeks. I'm still learning how to make reproducible questions so please let me know if there's anything I can do to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this. When you specify the formula, you need to set numeric variables to left of `~`:

```
#Code
controlSDs <- aggregate(data = controls2,Grain~.,
                        FUN = sd)
```

Output:

```
controlSDs
        Experiment Environment     Grain
1  Ceres- Clipping    Morris.1 154.67734
2 FGI- Defoliation  St. Paul.1  26.78905
```

Based on your attempts, this can also work:

```
#Code2
controlSDs <- aggregate(Grain~Experiment+Environment , data = controls2, sd)
```

Same output.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I made such a simple error on this syntax. What I'm looking for in the end is controlSDs <- aggregate( . ~ Experiment+Environment, data  = controls2, sd). It's a different output in the larger data set- it only has one entry for each combination of Experiment and Environment, and it runs across all 100+ columns.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
controls2 %>%
      group_by(Experiment, Environment) %>%
      summarise(Grain = sd(Grain))
```